# value read is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

Was following Play Frameworks's Scala Json api Docs when got this error :

value read is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue

My Imports are :

```
 import play.api.libs.json._       // JSON library
 import play.api.libs.json.Reads._ //custom validation helpers
 import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._   // Combinator syntax
```

and method throwing error is :

```
  def callSearchRoleRowInRoleService =  Action(parse.json) { 

  implicit request =>           

  var rolejson = request.body
  val roleId = (rolejson \ "roleId").read[Int]
  val shortDescription : Reads[String]= (rolejson \ "shortDescription").read[String]
  val description = (rolejson \ "description").read[String]    
  val activationDate = (rolejson \ "activationDate").read[java.sql.Date]
  val deactivationDate = (rolejson \ "deactivationDate").read[java.sql.Date]

  }
```

Working perfectly fine without read method

Answer (score 2):

You really ought to deserialize your data to a case class. `read[A]` is a method on `JsPath` in order to create `Reads[A]` to combine into a larger `Reads` object. As @drexin mentioned, you're probably looking for `as[A]`, however it is not a safe operation. If a single `as` fails, it throws an exception, which in your controller logic will result in a internal server error with little information to help the user.

You can construct `Reads` for a case class like this:

```
case class Role(id: Int, short: String, description: String, activation: java.sql.Date, deactivation: java.sql.Date)

object Role {
    implicit val reads: Reads[Role] = (
         (JsPath \ "roleId").read[Int] and 
         (JsPath \ "shortDescription").read[String] and 
         (JsPath \ "description").read[String] and 
         (JsPath \ "activationDate").read[java.sql.Date] and
         (JsPath \ "deactivationDate").read[java.sql.Date]
    )(Role.apply _)
}
```

Then your controller function would look more like this:

```
def callSearchRoleRowInRoleService =  Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>           
    request.body.validate[Role].fold(
        errors => { // handle validation errors, return some error message? },
        role => { // do something with the `role` to product a `Result` }
    )
}
```

The advantage of using `validate` is that all of the validation errors will be accumulated so they can be handled all at once, without throwing exceptions.

And because someone else is just *bound* to mention it, for simple case classes (like the one above), you can skip the combinators and use the macro:

```
 implicit val reads = Json.reads[Role]
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to use `read[A]` if you are using combinators to create a `Reads[A]`. The method you are looking for is `as[A]`.